# have only three number after comma in Double

Tags: java, casting, decimalformat

I'm trying to have only three numbers after the comma in my double value. I do:

```
DecimalFormat dfi_ = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
```

My double :

```
double myD = 6.082483660549182E-15;
System.out.println("DF Version of myD: " + dfi_.format(myD));
```

but the result was : `DF Version of myD: ,000`

Thanks,

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: What's your region/country (Locale)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is correct. It displays the (localized) number, with a precision of 3 digits after the decimal.

The value `6.082483660549182E-15` is `0.0000000000000060824..`, which is *very* close to 0.

Now, to display the number in Scientific Notation, consider a format of `"###.0E0"` - this should result in an output of `6,082E-15` (where the decimal is determined by locale), which I believe is desired.

(If the question is just about the comma, then that's merely a localization issue.)

Comment: Thank you this is what I'm looking for. with `new DecimalFormat("#.###E0");`

Comment: @user3551776 Cool, glad you found a solution!

Comment: a little problem is that I can have `6,082` instead of `6,082E-15`  or `6.082483660549182E-15`

Comment: @MeyLam If you want more control over the output you will have to add custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Find out your region (Locale) and use that locale specific `DecimalFormat`.

For more info have a look at [NumberFormat#getNumberInstance(Locale)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getNumberInstance%28java.util.Locale%29).

```
    double no = 123456.7890;

    for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
        NumberFormat numberFormat = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);

        System.out.println("========================================");
        System.out.println(locale.getDisplayCountry() + " - " + locale.toString());
        System.out.println(numberFormat.format(no));

        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
        String numberPattern = decimalFormat.toLocalizedPattern();
        System.out.println(numberPattern);
    }
```

output:

```
        ========================================
        Malaysia - ms_MY
        123,456.789
        #,##0.###
        ========================================
        Qatar - ar_QA
        123,456.789
        #,##0.###;#,##0.###-
        ========================================
        Iceland - is_IS
        123.456,789
        #.##0,###
        ========================================
        Finland - fi_FI
        123 456,789
        # ##0,###
        ========================================
         - pl
        123 456,789
        # ##0,###
        ========================================
        Malta - en_MT
        123,456.789
        #,##0.###

 and so on...
```